# Stream from webcam to RTMP (Mistserver)

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, rtmp, flash-video

I have Mistserver installed and try to find any tutorial how to send video from webcam to RTMP. Many tutorials shows only how to receive video but not how to send :-/ Have anybody here working example or link to working tutorial? HTML5 or Flash.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do so is probably using ffmpeg to pull in the webcam stream and deliver it over RTMP.

Something like this, for example:

ffmpeg -i *<webcam source here>* -acodec aac -ac 2 -strict experimental -ab 160k -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -profile:v baseline -level 30 -maxrate 10000000 -bufsize 10000000 -b 1000k -f flv rtmp://*<serveraddress>*/play/*<streamname>*